# array_push adds an empty row to my session

Tags: php, loops, session, for-loop, row

Hello i have a question.

I'm pretty new with php and working on an order-system.
Most things work fine for now but i still have problems with my sessions and it's driving my head crazy.

I'm building an order system with pulldowns. Every time there's an onChange event in a pulldown it triggers an php script which calls my database. Based on the results from the database it's given response data. When the user has complete the selection and clicks on "add" on the last page, this code is executing:

```
<?

$naam = $_POST['naam'];
$artikelgroep = $_POST['artikelgroep'];
$ras = $_POST['ras'];
$teeltvoorkeur = $_POST['teeltvoorkeur'];
$wortelverpakking = $_POST['wortelverpakking'];
$maat = $_POST['maat'];
$aantal = $_POST['aantal'];

$gegevens = array($naam, $artikelgroep, $ras, $teeltvoorkeur,    $wortelverpakking, $maat, $aantal);

if (!(isSet($_SESSION['product']))) {
    $_SESSION['product'] = array();
}
array_push($_SESSION['product'], $gegevens);
```

In a row-widget i've got this code:

```
<?
session_start();
$sessie = $_SESSION['product'];
?>

<?foreach ($sessie as $value) {?>
<tr>
<?foreach ($value as $waarde) {?>
<td><?echo $waarde?></td>
<?}?>
</tr>
<?}?>
```

(No space between t and r but it's seen as wrong??)
So, de data is succes fully push to $_SESSION['product']. But when i reload the page, navigate to another page or click again on the 'add-button' it add's an empty row?(!!!). Does anyone know what the problem could be, please?

Comment: you never check if a form was submitted, you just blindly suck in some POST data and push onto the array. try `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { ... push ... }` to guard against GET requests pushing invalid data.

Comment: I am not entirely sure but maybe try iterating through your session arrays like this : `foreach ($arr as $key=>$val)` rather than just this: `foreach ($arr as $key)`

Comment: Carefull : `isSet` => `isset`

Comment: @MarcB I think your comment should be rather posted as an answer.

Comment: Wow, Marc B.. thank you so much! it works!!